# Getting an error while building the react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, babeljs

We are using Jetty server and '

```
gulp dev'
```

command to run our react app. App is getting started well. But after making a first change in the app code, I am getting the below error.

Is there an issue with the babel? Because the app is getting started for the very first time but only after making any change the build starts failing.

```
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open '[path].js'
[15:47:15] 'webpack-dev' errored after 6.77 min
[15:47:15] Error: 1
    at formatError (C:\Users\[path]\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^3.7.0\format-error.js:20:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\[path]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^3.7.0\log\events.js:41:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (D:\Work\Portal\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at D:\Work\Portal\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (D:\Work\Portal\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (D:\Work\Portal\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Work\Portal\gulpfile.js:152:3)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
```

I am expecting the watch function to build the app after a code change.